# How does TCP PSH work?

Tags: networking, tcp

PSH is a way to send data via TCP. Besides that, I can find very little info on how to implement it properly.

Here is what interests me:

1. Let's say, server window is 8000 bytes, and I send 2 requests with 150 and 600 bytes. Do I get some sort of confirmation that the data has been received? Can I somehow trigger a confirmacion?
2. I've seen some ACK packets, which does not contain PSH but do contain some sort of payload data (Wireshark marks it as "TCP segment data"). Is this data passed on to user, and if it is, why do we need PSH flag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TCP PSH generally doesn't 'work' at all. Berkely-derived TCP implementations completely ignore it.

Source: W.R. Stevens, *TCP/IP Illustrated,* vol I: 20.5 PUSH Flag.

Comment: does that mean that all payload data should be delivered to the end-user, included the one sent without PSH flag?

Comment: @ArsenZahray Yes it does. All the data goes straight into the socket receive buffer regardless of the PSH flag.

Comment: “Today, however, most APIs don't provide a way for the application to tell its TCP to set the
PUSH flag. Indeed, many implementors feel the need for the PUSH flag is outdated, and a
good TCP implementation can determine when to set the flag by itself.  ”

，  I don't think the author means that the PSH flag is ignored, it's just the client doesn't provide a low-level API to set it manually, but they will set it automatically.

Comment: @luochen1990 And then what? The data goes into the receiver's socket receive buffer and then his read or his `select()` unblocks immediately, all without any reference to the PSH flag. It's redundant. It was designed for an interrupting API which has never seen the light of day.

Comment: Isn't push flag used to separate different messages of an application or force transmitting the assembled data to application due to not enough size in the buffer?

Comment: @slinkin No it isn't, and it could not possibly be used for that purpose. It doesn't provide message boundaries, and it doesn't force anything, as W.R. Stevens said all those years ago.

Answer (score 2):

@Arsen: Answering to the second part of your question "why do we need PSH flag?"
The PSH flag in the TCP header informs the receiving host that the data should be pushed up to the receiving application immediately.
We are using PSH flag to exchange Time Stamp value between two servers.

Comment: Should be pushed up how? Via what API?

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming , if we set push flag , packet wont wait in  receive buffer , it will directly send to receiver.

Comment: How? The application would need to be issuing a read, in which case the transfer will happen anyway. The PSH flag doesn't make any difference to that.

Comment: On many TCP implementions the read will not return immediately, until 0.5 second has elapsed, or a segment with the PSH flag has been received - to allow multiple segments to be combined efficiently.

Comment: @Simon Really? Your source for that assertion?

Answer (score -1):

The data doesn't sit waiting in the receive buffer anyhow.
TCP apps must go out of their way to have the TCP layer bulk up a few packets and deliver full data buffers.
In fact its somewhat frustrating to see applications allocate 64KB buffers to receive data and see them getting a gazillion 1480/1472 byte messages.

Comment: "The data doesn't sit waiting in the receive buffer anyhow." Really? What happens to it instead? Answer: nothing, until the application issues a read.