# Is it ok to send some part of the HTTP body with its header?

Tags: http, tcp

User space HTTP libraries usually write headers separately from the body to the kernel like the Golang library (http.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader()).
But Is it ok by RFCs that the user-space library marshal the whole HTTP request header and body together, and writes some of them (e.g. 4Kb) that include the full HTTP header and some part of the body to the kernel (send to other side) and writes some other in another request to the kernel (send to other side)?
If it is Ok, please send references in HTTP RFCs.

It is about buffering and performance concerns. If RFCs do not let libraries send some part of the body with headers, parser logic, and memory management will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it is Ok, please send references in HTTP RFCs.

HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 are using TCP as the underlying transport protocol. TCP is a streaming protocol, i.e. there is no concept of a message but the TCP connection is bidirectional stream of bytes.

Because the data is only an unstructured stream of bytes the TCP stack is free to combine multiple `send` into the same packet, split a `send` into multiple packets etc. Similar a `recv` might return the data included in part of a packet, data from multiple packets etc.

Any HTTP/1 or HTTP/2 stack which makes assumptions about `recv` only returning the header or even returning the full header is broken by design.

Comment: I know TCP is a streaming protocol, But in practice, many TCP senders use the Push flag to indicate the segment of data they have sent needs to be delivered to the receiver before awaiting additional data. 

Do you know another mechanism in TCP protocol that let TCP stream (library) return to `recv` caller without any error situation(I don't want to include any error exceptions in this question)?

Comment: If say No to the above question, How a TCP library must know and send PSH flag? I think we say to it in e.g. HTTP by providing some data.
So back to the first step, Is it OK to send some part of the body with the header in calling TCP `send` to let TCP set the PSH flag on?

Comment: @OmidHekayati: *"... many TCP senders use the Push flag to indicate the segment of data they have sent needs to be delivered to the receiver before awaiting additional data."*  - I don't think that this is actually the case. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059521/3081018. Apart from that what reasoning about the PSH flag has to do with your original question. PSH flag can not be used as a kind of message delimiter in the stream (there is no such thing) and does not affect how much data `recv` returns.

Comment: So if the TCP stream (library) buffer is full in sender or receiver can return to `recv` without setting the PSH flag. And in this case, we can't distinguish between the PSH flag from the sender (HTTP) or TCP decides to return. However, when the peer TCP receives the data, it will naturally buffer them and won’t disturb the application for each and every byte.
So I think in this way as you say we MUST not makes assumptions about `recv` only returning the header or even returning the full header in first attempt.

Comment: @OmidHekayati: `recv` returns if any data are available, i.e. the receive buffer does not need to be full. It returns with all data received so far (or less if the size argument to `recv` is less than what is available in the receive buffer).

Comment: You are right, But keep in mind that in the first attempt usually, TCP is established just before call `recv`, so usually there is no data in the TCP stream read buffer to return without any error. so depends on blocking or non-blocking next `recv`, we usually get data when the PSH flag is on or the buffer is full.